# Performance of flat directory structures in iOS

Tags: ios, performance, directory, filesystems

On the iOS filesystem, is there a way to optimize file access performance by using a **tiered** directory structure vs. a **flat** directory structure?

Specifically, my app has `Objects` that each contain a number of images and data files.  A user could create thousands of these `Objects` and I need to optimize access to one image for ~100 arbitrary `Objects` at a time.

In this situation, how should I organize files on the filesystem?  Would a **tiered** directory structure be faster than a **flat** one?  And if so, how should I structure the tiered system (i.e. how many tiers, and how many subdirectories / files per tier)?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you might as well try it with a flat structure to see if it is slow or not.  Perhaps apple has put in code to optimize how files are found and you don't even need to worry about this.  You can probably build out the whole app and just test how quickly it loads and see if that meets your requirements.

If you need to speed it up I would suggest trying to make some sort of structure based on the name of the file.  You could have a folder which has all of the items beginning with the letter 'a' or 'b' and so on and so forth. This would split it into 26 folders which should significantly decrease the amount of items in each.  Depending on how you name the files you might want a different scheme so that each of the folders had a similar amount of items in it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Core Data, you could always just enable the `Allows External Storage` option in the attribute of your model and let the system decide where it should go.[image]

That would be a decent first step to see if the performance is ok.